# Translation of a finite set and lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ a finite set and $E \subset \mathbb{R} $ a lebesgue measurable set and $m(E)>0$.Prove that $\exists x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\exists s>0$ such that $x+sA \subset E$.

I tried to use fubini's theorem and the steinhauss theorem without success.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: How could you use Fubini or Steinhaus here?

Comment: i assuemed that because of the fact that E has e possitive measure i can translate it and dilate it into an inetrval and then proove somehow that all the points of x+sA lie in E.

Comment: By Steinhaus they mean this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem) theorem presumably.

Comment: @user293794: Thanks, I was presuming a different result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Theorem 3 [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rae/1339694107). The main ingredient is the Lebesgue density theorem, which you should attempt to use for this problem if you have not already.

Comment: thank you for your help.The lebesgue density theorem seems in general to be a very useful tool!

Comment: It is often useful for this sort of problem - for instance it also allows you to prove the Steinhauss theorem. You should also look into the Lebesgue differentiation theorem which generalizes the Lebesgue density theorme.

Comment: yes of course! thank  you!